# How should I test for Navigator.pushNamed() in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, testing, mocking, mockito, navigator

I have a test where I'm trying to observe the behaviour of the `Navigator` when the app navigates from `page1.dart` to `page2.dart` (push) and back (pop). Using verify from the Mockito package, I can successfully verify that the push behaviour works when I am not using `pushNamed()`. However, after I changed my project to use Named Route, I wasn't able to find a correct way to implement the mock and test the navigation.

Is there a proper way how to check, that Navigator was called? Or is there a recommended way to mock and replace the `navigator`?

Edit: I found a flutter library [Mockingjay](https://pub.dev/packages/mockingjay/score) to Mock the Navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a flutter library [Mockingjay](https://pub.dev/packages/mockingjay/score) to Mock the Navigator.

Here is an example on their GitHub page on testing Navigator.

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('pushes SettingsPage when TextButton is tapped', (tester) async {
    final navigator = MockNavigator();
    when(() => navigator.push(any())).thenAnswer((_) async {});

    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        home: MockNavigatorProvider(
          navigator: navigator,
          child: const MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );

    await tester.tap(find.byType(TextButton));

    verify(
      () => navigator.push(any(that: isRoute<void>(whereName: equals('/settings')))),
    ).called(1);
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define `routes` in your `MaterialApp`:

```
routes: {
    // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
    '/': (context) => const FirstScreen(),
    // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
    '/second': (context) => const SecondScreen(),
  },
```

And then use `Navigator` to Push to your destination:

`Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');`

For more details check this flutter doc on [Navigate with named routes.](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes)

Answer (score -3):

```
OnPressed:() {
     Navigator.push( context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (context) => NewScreen()
       )
      );
    },
```

Comment: Question is regarding unit testing not normal navigation